# "Invalid object name"Error in fluent nhibernate configuration

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent nhibernate in my application and I also use sql server 2012. this is my configuration:

```
public class SessionFactory
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        public static string ConnectionString
        {
            get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ECommerceConnectionString"].ToString(); }
        }

        private static void Initialize()
        {
            var config = Fluently.Configure().Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration
                    .MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(ConnectionString).ShowSql().Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>());
            _sessionFactory = config.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ContactMapping>()).BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        private static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
                Initialize();

            return _sessionFactory;
        }

        private static ISession GetNewSession()
        {
            return GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();
        }

        public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
        {
            var sessionStorageContainer = SessionStorageFactory.GetStorageContainer();

            var currentSession = sessionStorageContainer.GetCurrentSession();

            if (currentSession == null)
            {
                currentSession = GetNewSession();
                sessionStorageContainer.Store(currentSession);
            }

            return currentSession;
        }
    }
```

although I'm using `MsSql2012Dialect` but I still got the sql server compatibility error, how can I fix this please??

Comment: can you post the full exception? "invalid object name" looks too generic

Answer (score 0):

You should really use

```
 Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration
                .MsSql2012
                .ConnectionString(conString)
                .ShowSql)
```

works for me fluently

The error "Invalid object name" usually references to a SQL exception that for example a table does not exist or something like that... A full stack trace/error message would help.